# Python read files in directory and concatenate

Tags: python, file

I want to write a Python script that searches all folders in the current directory, looks for all `.txt` files, and creates a file that is a concatenation of all those files (in any order) in the current directory. If folders have subfolders, it should not search those subfolders. An example is

```
main_folder
  folder_1
    sub_folder
      file1.txt
    file2.txt
  folder_2
    file3.txt
```

The script is placed inside `main_folder`. It should create a file that is a concatenation of `file2.txt` and `file3.txt` (in any order) inside `main_folder`.

My question is: How can I tell Python to traverse through the folders, look for `.txt` files, without going into the subfolders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [glob](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html):

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('main_folder/*/*.txt')
['main_folder/folder_1/file2.txt', 'main_folder/folder_2/file3.txt']
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk):

> When *topdown* is `True`, the caller can modify the *dirnames* list in-place (perhaps using `del` or slice assignment), and `walk()` will only recurse into the subdirectories whose names remain in *dirnames*; this can be used to prune the search, impose a specific order of visiting, or even to inform `walk()` about directories the caller creates or renames before it resumes `walk()` again.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [os.walk()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) function with the `topdown` option set to True. The delete all the `dirnames` in the returned tuple:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/base/dir', topdown=True):
    del dirs[:]
...
```

Comment: Why should I delete the `dirnames`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Unix based system .. I think the easiest way would be to use `find` and `cat` using the python `subprocess` module, like this. With `find` the `-depth` option really helps, for example, use `-depth +3` to find all files at a depth >= 3

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> lst = subprocess.check_output('find . -name "*.txt" -depth 2', shell=True)
>>> print lst
./folder_1/f1.txt
./folder_2/f2.txt 
>>> out_f = subprocess.check_output('cat '+lst.replace('\n', ' '), shell=True)
>>> print out_f
inside Folder_1
inside Folder 2
```

You can avoid the `shell=True` by providing each argument separately.